# Chosen working on one select but not other selects

Tags: drupal, jquery-chosen

I'm facing a strange problem. I'm using `chosen` drupal plugin. I've have 3 term-reference fields added to a content-type.

While editing & adding any nodes of this content-type, chosen UI interface is applied & working with all 3 fields.

Now, I created a view and exposed the filters for all these three term-reference fields. In the view, chosen UI interface is applied only to one field and not applied to the rest.

In the settings of chosen module (admin/config/user-interface/chosen)
`Apply Chosen to the following elements` is set to `select`

These are the Drupal settings outputed by Drupal into javascript:

```
"chosen":{
  "selector":"select",
  "minimum_single":"20",
  "minimum_multiple":"20",
  "minimum_width":"300",
  "search_contains":true,
  "disable_search":false,
  "disable_search_threshold":"Never Apply",
  "placeholder_text_multiple":"Choose some options",
  "placeholder_text_single":"Choose an option",
  "no_results_text":"No results match",
  "multiple":{
     "field_tags_tid[]":true,
     "field_working_area_tid":false,
     "field_published_in_tid[]":true
  },
  "max_selected_options":{
     "field_tags_tid[]":false,
     "field_working_area_tid":false,
     "field_published_in_tid[]":false
  }
   }
}
```

what might be the problem? How to rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your problem is, but the chosen module has settings at: admin/config/user-interface/chosen.
add selector strings to the textfield marked "Apply Chosen to the following elements".

Comment: as you can see from the configuration that I've pasted ` "selector":"select",` the selector string is set to `select`

Comment: Ahh. It's late here, I missed that. I used the chosen module on a project last week without problems. I am going to assume you checked for javascript errors on the page.